# Find if jQuery object exists in Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've a Javascript array and pushing the elements for later usage like this:

```
var array = [jQuery('.first').eq(0)];
```

Now if I try to check if the same element in array exists, it returns -1

```
jQuery.inArray(jQuery('.first').eq(0), array)
```

What is the perfect way to find if the object exists in array or not.

Comment: That provides if objects are equal or not but how to find if the object is in array or not without using for loop

Comment: @Manish, that's because there is no way to coerce `inArray()` into making a special case for jQuery objects. Therefore, you'll have to write a custom loop. Of course, you can wrap that loop in a function if you're so inclined.

Comment: Ok Finally I did it using array iteration with for loop